Instant freeze Remote Desktop with iPhone and SSH
I am using iSH and RD  Client to connect as local host with a secure file to my windows server. Before that I was only using the RD client und the Server IP. There was no problem. But now the client freezes after 1s. If I’m fast I can touch one thing on the sever. But than it’s over. Nothing.
I don’t see anything on the iSH app either.
Do I have to configure something in windows ?
When I’m connection with ssh the secure file and my mac I don’t have this problem
Restarted, uninstalled, reinstalled, another RD Client

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
